# Improving this Raspberry Pi question

Tags: discussion, editing

How can I improve the question [How well is the Raspberry Pi's performance?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1474/37)

I do not want to delete it if it can be made better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time it was closed [your question was](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/revisions/1474/1):

> #### Is the Raspberry Pi too good to be true?
>
> The Raspberry Pi motherboard is $25-35 depending on the model purchased. It seems like the Raspberry Pi would be provide poor performance for that price. For such a low price, does the Raspberry Pi work well or does the device have many issues?

There are several problems here.

Firstly, it isn't actually about *robotics* so it really should have been closed as off-topic and migrated to [Raspberry Pi stack exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Sadly if we had done this, it would still have been put on hold due to the other problems. It is simply just too broad. Does the Raspberry Pi work well *for what*? Does it have many issues when *doing what*? There is a huge difference between doing some light web browsing or python coding and trying to implement a [SLAM system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping) for controlling a mobile robot.

That is why all stack exchange sites prefer [*practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face*](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) since *Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page*.

---

Your question [is currently](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/revisions/1474/2):

> #### How well is the Raspberry Pi's performance?
>
> How well is the Raspberry Pi's performance? By this, I mean can the Raspberry Pi handle applications like Python3 interpreter, BASH scripts, coffeescript, javascript, and web browsers as well as current laptops? How does the Raspberry Pi compare to Android devices? The reason I ask is because it seems like a $25-35 motherboard and CPU would not work well.

Primarily this still it isn't actually about *robotics*, so at best it should be migrated.

This is still asking for opinions without any practical focus. As such it would almost certainly be closed over on [Raspberry Pi stack exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) for these same reasons. Since I don't want to migrate a question which they would close anyway, I would rather leave it closed here until you have decided whether you can make it into a viable question.

For other resources, I would suggest that you look at our [About page](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/about) and our [Help Centre](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Thanks for your eagerness to improve your question, I hope this answer helps you understand what you need to do to ask practical questions in the future.

Comment: Wow! A StackExchange site for Raspberry Pi?! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry @DevynCollierJohnson - If I'd known that you didn't know about it, I'd have linked to the site before now. Raspberry Pi SE has been going longer than *robotics* has, before even the RasPi was out!

Comment: Do not worry about it @MarkBooth. If you were a mind reader, you would not bother using StackExchange (^u^)